# Requests fail when extra packages are installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, request, package

I had these packages in my server:

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    request,
    make_response,
    send_from_directory,
    send_file,
    render_template,
    redirect,
    url_for,
    current_app,
)
import json
import os
import subprocess
import sys
```

And this line worked fine: `data = request.get_json()`

Then i had to add some more packages:

```
import requests
from urllib import request
from urllib.parse import urlencode
```

and now i get this error in that line:

```
AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'get_json'
```

Something is broken and i don't know how to find it.

Comment: The problem is that you imported `request` from two different libraries. The last one takes precedence when you use the name.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I changed `from urllib import request` to from `urllib import request as rqst`. Then, `data = rqst.get_json()` gives me: `AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'get_json'
`.

Comment: You are mixing up two libs. `get_json()` comes from requests, not urllib.

Comment: Stupid question perhaps, but do you even use urllib in your code? I understand you provided the minimum to reproduce the problem but if there are libs you don't need, remove the import statements. And if you have a large number of functions, it can make sense to split the code in several files. Each file can have its own imports statements and import only the libs that are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two definitions for the same name. If you do

```
import request
from urllib import request
```

then `request` now refers to `urllib.request`, not the `request` module, since the second `import` redefines the name.

Change the second one to

```
import urllib
```

and then use `urllib.request` to refer to that module. `request` by itself will still refer to the `request` module, so `request.get_json()` will continue to work.

Comment: I get this now: `AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'get_json'`

Comment: It should be `request.get_json()`.

Comment: The line is: `data = = urllib.request.get_json()`.

Comment: Why are you adding `urllib` there? That's the same as the original problem, you don't want to use `request` from `urllib` there.

Comment: Yeah. It worked but this line broke now `req = request.Request(url_for_auth, method="POST")`. So what do you suggest? What should i delete?

Comment: That one should be `urllib.request`.

Comment: You have to decide which one should be qualified and which one shouldn't be, and use them consistently.

Comment: When i change that line to what you suggested, i get `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
`.

Comment: Do I really have to spell it out? `urllib.request.Request(...)`